Trying to run Flet in my Mobile device, how can I program with Flet in my phone?
when I tried to run my Flet Code on my phone this happened:
ImportError: dlopen failed: library "/root/py_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic_core/_pydantic core.cpython-311.so" needed or dlopened by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libpython3.11.so.1.0" is not accessible for the namespace "(default)"

How can I solve this? Keep in mind that I use my phone to programming
I tried to reinstall dependencies, that flet it's installed in my device and more
I hope someone could help me with this issue, don't know what to do.
